# Переход в ViewController из GameScene

Tags: xcode, swift, spritekit, storyboard, swift3

Я делаю игру на Swift 3.0 SpriteKit.

Главное меню у меня находится в сториборде на ViewController'е. Я легко могу переходить из Контроллера к Контроллеру, от Сцены к Сцене. Но абсолютно не понимаю как переходить из сцены в меню и наоборот.

Comment: Каким образом сцена появляется на экране?

Comment: Идет нажатие на кнопку, считывается название кнопки, собирается название и переходит на нужную сцену.
buttonTitle -- название кнопки.
`let skView = SKView(frame: self.view.frame)
sceneView = GameScene(fileNamed: "Level "+buttonTitle)
skView.presentScene(sceneView)`

Comment: Переход по сценам в самой игре. `let currentScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "Level "+String(thisScene)) let transition = SKTransition.doorway(withDuration: 0.5)
                currentScene!.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
                self.scene!.view?.presentScene(currentScene!, transition: transition)`

Comment: skView ведь куда-то добавляется? ДУмаю, что надо удалить его с той вьюхи на которую она была добавлена